# ProcessMaker docker image looks stuck

Tags: docker, processmaker

I got processmaker/pm4-core:4.1.20. Am trying to run it on Docker Desktop. It keeps repeating

> - echo 'Waiting for mysql'
>
> Waiting for mysql
>
> - sleep 1
> - mysqladmin ping -u pm -ppass -h mysql --silent
>
> mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface
> can be insecure.

And is stuck. I guess I should be able to access it in url://localhost:443.

[edit]
I also tried using this

> docker run -d --name processmaker --network pm-network  
> -v /path/to/env/file:/opt/processmaker/.env  
> -v /path/to/storage:/opt/processmaker/storage  
> -v /path/to/docker/tls/certs:/certs  
> -v /path/to/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs/processmaker-ssl 
> -e DOCKER_HOST=tcp://remotedocker:2376  
> -e DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 
> -e DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs 
> -p 8080:443 
> processmaker/pm4-core:4.0-dev
> from docker image page but still the same problem. (Though I had to remove --network pm-network and change the version).

Comment: You can also try using our kubernetes helm install here: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/processmaker/processmaker

Answer (score 1):

Here are the simple steps for you to run ProcessMaker through Docker :

1. git clone https://github.com/ProcessMaker/pm4core-docker.git
2. cd /pm4core-docker
3. docker-compose up